# Drag gesture only if I start dragging on top of the view that I want to be dragged

Tags: swiftui

I want a view to be dragged only if I start dragging on that view. Currently, if I start dragging from anywhere on the screen and then dragged over it, it drags.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .offset(offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        offset = gesture.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        offset = CGSize.zero
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. Place a view behind the view you want draggable, such as a `Color`. Place a `DragGesture` on that to capture the drag if you miss the view you actually want draggable. This has to be a view that will be shown on screen, or this doesn't work, i.e. you can't use `Color.clear`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Place a Color behind your view, set to the background color.
            // It can't be clear as that doesn't work.
            Color.white
                // Place a DragGesture there to capture the drag if not on the view you want
                .gesture(DragGesture())
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .offset(offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        offset = gesture.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        offset = CGSize.zero
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me even without setting a drag gesture for the color.